# Can I migrate color scheme from JetBrains to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jetbrains-ide

I'm migrating my development environment from JetBrains to VSCode.

But I can't use my color scheme from JetBrains on VSCode.

How can I do?

Comment: try some plugins, here is one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trinm1709.dracula-theme-from-intellij&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you this extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rokoroku.vscode-theme-darcula

Also, i made my own settings to change interface of whole ide with terminal, panel etc.

settings.json:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.background": "#232425",
        "editorGutter.background": "#232425",
        "activityBar.background": "#2F3032",
        "sideBarSectionHeader.background": "#2F3032",
        "sideBar.background": "#2F3032",
        "terminal.foreground": "#678046",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#2F7ECD",
        "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#d37e02",
        "terminal.background": "#242424",
    },
```

[And it looks very similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQEBM.png)

Comment: I'm using DK Monokai on Jetbrains. And I fixed several things on the theme 

Comment: @SnKinos I also have migrated to VSC and i was changing everything by myself, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color - here you can find all colors that can be changed